# Download images from encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com using Python

Tags: python

I am doing scraping of images from Google. I got image link in my script but this have this format

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQh6rPd9hx_fUGzorshx1fG5kzUM5FGCSYmm2YBuLU3uSFFI5BviIWd6hrHbw&s

I opened and here  is the image but I cant use urllib.urlretrieve(imagenurl,imagen) for downdload.

Someone know other way for download ?
I am using python 2.7

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

def run():
    palabra ='pez'
    response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q={}&hl=es&sxsrf=ALeKk00KoMQKffGLNWV5UEKbuPwpySPuig:1596391733831&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiajd7Rjv3qAhXqTN8KHSINBkcQ_AUoAXoECBoQAw&biw=1262&bih=593'.format(palabra))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
    imagenes = soup.find_all('img')

    for i in range(1,5):
        imagen_i = imagenes[i]['src']
        imagen = imagen_i.split('/')[-1]
        print(imagen_i)
        #urllib.urlretrieve(imagen_i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: > "I am using python 2.7." Stop. Right now. Upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: why do you can't use `urlretrieve` ? Do you get some error or what? Always put error message in question.

Comment: I have no problem to download it with `urlretrieve` on Linux but you should check `print(imagen)` to see what filenames you use. It gives names like `images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQh6rPd9hx_fUGzorshx1fG5kzUM5FGCSYmm2YBuLU3uSFFI5BviIWd6hrHbw&s` with chars which may not be allowed in your system - so they may not saved - and you should rather create filenames manually - ie. `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` , ... `"{}.jpg".format(i)`

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem to download it with `urlretrieve` on Linux but you should check `print(imagen)` to see what filenames you use.

It gives names like

```
images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQh6rPd9hx_fUGzorshx1fG5kzUM5FGCSYmm2YBuLU3uSFFI5BviIWd6hrHbw&s
```

with chars which may not be allowed in your system - so it may not save it - and you should rather create filenames manually - ie. `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, ..., `"{}.jpg".format(i)` - or you should remove not allowed chars from filename.

---

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

palabra ='pez'

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q={}&hl=es&sxsrf=ALeKk00KoMQKffGLNWV5UEKbuPwpySPuig:1596391733831&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiajd7Rjv3qAhXqTN8KHSINBkcQ_AUoAXoECBoQAw&biw=1262&bih=593'.format(palabra))
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
all_images = soup.find_all('img')

for i, img in enumerate(all_images[1:5], 1):
    src = img['src']
    print 'src:', src
    
    filename = src.split('/')[-1]
    print 'filename:', filename

    #import urlparse
    #parts = urlparse.urlparse(src)
    #query = urlparse.parse_qs(parts.query)
    #q = query['q'][0]
    #filename = q.split(':')[1]
    #print 'filename:', filename
            
    filename = '{}.jpg'.format(i)
    print 'filename:', filename
    
    urllib.urlretrieve(src, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IMG_FOLDER="/some/folder/directory/IMAGES/"

for i in image_url_list:
    response = requests.get(i[0], headers=headers, stream=True, timeout=1)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        file_loc=IMG_FOLDER+i[1]+".png"
        with open(file_loc, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response:
                f.write(chunk)
```

Where the image_url_list consists of sublists which have first item `[0]` being the URL type as you stated, and `[1]` some random name I've allocated with UUID4.

I think this method should be much faster than the one shown above.